# REST API Social News Feed with Images throwing 400 error

Tags: 2013, rest

Reading the news feed with the REST API _api/social.feed/my/news gives me text, but if an Image post is added, without text, I get a 400 error. If I added text, I am shown the text and get no error.

No Text with Image = ERROR (400 bad request error);

Text with Image = NO ERROR;

Any thoughts or direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug in Microsoft product. We also faced the same issue for 3 months, then they confirmed us about the bus.